# This is the most candid photo among all those directed photos

Tags: grammar, word-choice

So I was kind of going to make fun of my friend's friend because it looked candid but was actually fully directed.

In this case should I say

> this is the most candid photo among all these directed photos
>   this is the most candid photo among all directed photos

I'm not referring to any specific directed photos, but the second sentence sounds a bit odd to me for no reason. Let me know what is the best way of saying it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *directed photos*? I have never heard that expression before. Is your actual question about the use of *these*? (That's the only difference between your two sentences.) Note that using *these* ***does*** specify a specific set of photos.

Comment: I meant some photos that have directors and the directors ask people to pose or move and that, so I was using it as the opposite of candid photos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"These" would be used when you are pointing out to some specific objects (photos).
But, when talking about something specific (the directed photos) without meaning to pointing at them, you can simply use the "**THE**" article.

As in this case:
"This is the most candid photo among all **the** directed photos."